# How do not use all non-named groups in Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

In .NET you can make all non-named groups non-capturing by setting RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture, but Java does not have such features. Perhaps someone solved a similar problem ? I see only one way is to try to parse my long expression and try to cut all unnamed groups

Comment: `(?:regex)` like in any other?

Comment: I mean a case, when I have a long expression, and there are both unnamed groups and named groups and I want to turn ALL unnamed groups off at once. Here is some details about it:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html
As for (?:regex) you can only turn one unnamed group off.

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post clarifications in comments. Not all comments may be shown initially. Make it easy for others to help you. Put everything in the question. Include an example.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the story I just wrote an other regex, which found all non-named groups and after that I changed it to non-capturing groups.
Here is this regex: (?\w*)(\s*)(?Music\s*)(Store)
and when we process all steps describing before, we get next regex:
customer:\s*(?\w*)(?:\s*)(?Music\s*)(?:Store)